# Надо добавить строку в сообщение исключения в существующем коде на F#, а я что-то не могу понять как

Tags: .net, dll, f#

В общем имеется такая вещь. Unicorn Engine. Позволяет запустить эмуляцию разных процессоров. К нему имеется готовая надстройка для .NET, вот только написана на F#. А там, когда не может создать объект собственно движка выдает ошибку типа: "XX,  Unable to create Unicorn engine".

```
let checkResult(errCode: Int32, errMsg: String) =
    if errCode <> Common.UC_ERR_OK then raise(ApplicationException(String.Format("{0}. Error: {1}", errMsg, errCode))
```

в самом движке есть функция char* strrerror(int code); И она даже импортируется *(но вот тут , я идумаю что проблема, импортируется она как IntPtr strerror(Int))*
попытка сделать в лоб вот так:

```
let checkResult(errCode: Int32, errMsg: String) =
    if errCode <> Common.UC_ERR_OK then raise(ApplicationException(String.Format("{0}. Error: {1} {2}", errMsg, errCode, binding.Strerror(errCode)))
```

вызывает появление ошибки в следующем let

> Ошибка    2   Возможно, неправильные отступы: этот маркер находится вне контекста, начиная с позиции (50:45). Попробуйте увеличить отступ маркера или использовать стандартные соглашения о форматировании.   F:.projects.cpp.msvc\UnicornManaged\Unicorn.fs   52  5   UnicornManaged

предполагаю, что проблема в том, что функция импортирована как IntPtr а не String. (Хотя, может я и что-то не так сделал синтаксически. Все же я этот язык не знаю нифига)

```
[<AutoOpen>]
    module private Imported = 
. . . 
        [<DllImport("unicorn", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
        extern IntPtr uc_strerror(Int32 err)
. . .
let instance =
    {new IBinding with
. . .
        member thi.Strerror(err) = uc_strerror(err)
. . .
}
```

Кто знаком с этим F#? Подскажите как поправить код

Comment: Вопрос в интеропе. Откуда у вас декларация P/Invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
[<DllImport("unicorn", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)>]
extern string uc_strerror(Int32 err)
```

Comment: Возможно вам будет это интересно - в [F# Slack](http://fsharp.org/guides/slack/) открылся канал для обсуждения F# на русском языке. Для того, чтобы туда попасть нужно только присоединиться к [F# Software Foundation](http://foundation.fsharp.org/join), после этого вы должны получить приглашение в slack

Comment: вроде как разобрался чуток. скомпилировалось вот так. ` let сheckResult(errCode: Int32, errMsg: String) = if errCode <> Common.UC_ERR_OK then  let errorStringPtr = binding.Strerror(errCode)
    let msg = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errorStringPtr)             
    raise( ApplicationException(String.Format("{0}. Error: {1} {2}", errMsg, errCode, msg )))` пока не буду проверять, как оно ошибки показывает, т.к. основная необходимость не в этом коде, а в том. что им пользуется. а там я разобрался что была за ошибка.  P.S. Никак не могу разобраться с каментами, вернее с их оформлением

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как разобрался чуток. Скомпилировалось вот так.

```
let checkResult(errCode: Int32, errMsg: String) = 
    if errCode <> Common.UC_ERR_OK then 
         let errorStringPtr = binding.Strerror(errCode)
         let msg = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(errorStringPtr)             
         raise( ApplicationException(String.Format("{0}. Error: {1} {2}", errMsg, errCode, msg )))
```

Пока не буду проверять, как оно ошибки показывает, т.к. основная необходимость сейчас не в этом коде, а в том. что им пользуется. А там я разобрался что была за ошибка. Как закончу, проверю.

P.S. Никак не разберусь с оформлением каментов здесь. все время выходит одним куском...

P.P.S. bohdan_trotsenko, ваш вариант тоже не вызывал ошибок, но в самом Unicorn, использовалась функция в виде IntPtr (там я и подсмотрел, то что сделал). Я не стал править код во многих местах, предпочел поменять в одном, хотя сам бы сделал вашим вариантом (на C# я так и делал, в схожих случаях)

Comment: кстати, рекомендую http://pinvoke.net